# Redundant Rails Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

Why is it that my `<%= form_for charges_path %>` returns an undefined local variable when visiting /product/:product with these routes :

```
  get 'product/:product'      => 'charges#new'
  post 'product/:product'     => 'charges#create'
```

but works when I add these?

```
  resources :charges, :only => [:new, :create]
```

I'd like to clean this up

Comment: pass @charges instance from your controller to the view.

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your problem, but I've noticed that when you manually create routes vs using the resources helper the path helpers are different. The resources routes will create charges_path & charge_path, but the manual get/post may only create charge_path. So check your path helpers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `get` and `post` methods you don't get the path helpers created, ie. there is no `charges_path` method unless you provide a string with the `:as` option.

So without `charges_path` method, ruby thinks it's the name of a variable and so you get the error you're getting.